# IE11 Flexbox issue using a Bootstrap .badge

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-4

Currently, I have a `flex-row` that has one element grows with the space and a badge that justifies to the end and should not grow. But in IE11 with `flex-grow: 0`, the `span.badge` will not even take the width of the content inside of it. Any idea how to get the `span.badge` to just be the size of the content inside of it?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvmwNY

```css
#sector-form-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.form-check-with-badge {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-check-with-badge .form-check {
  flex: 1;
}

.form-check-with-badge .form-check label {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-check-with-badge .badge {
  flex: 0;
}

.form-check-with-badge .badge {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 0.4rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="sector-form-wrapper" class="">
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Apt">
              Apartment
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill" style="background-color: rgb(0, 128, 128);">
            344
          </span></div>
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Ret">
              Retail
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill" style="background-color: rgb(159, 191, 127);">
            283
          </span></div>
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Off">
              Office
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill" style="background-color: rgb(127, 159, 191);">
            200
          </span></div>
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Hot">
              Hotel
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill">
            49
          </span></div>
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Gen">
              Other
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill">
            29
          </span></div>
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Ind">
              Industrial
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill" style="background-color: rgb(191, 159, 127);">
            22
          </span></div>
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Spc">
              Specialty Properties
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill">
            8
          </span></div>
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Snr">
              Seniors Housing
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill">
            6
          </span></div>
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Aff">
              Affordable Housing
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill">
            5
          </span></div>
  <div class="form-check-with-badge">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Lnd">
              Land
            </label></div> <span class="badge badge-pill">
            5
          </span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove the `flex:0` from the `.badge`

Comment: The shorthand `flex: 0` resolves to `flex: 0 1 0`, which mean _dont grow, allow shrink, content size zero_, so remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: And btw, note that you write `flex-grow: 0` in the text but use `flex: 0,` in the code, and those two are not the same. And to change it to `flex-grow: 0` would be pointless, since that is the default value.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you so very much. This solved the issue. I learned now that the shorthand does indeed resolve differently or at least gets rendered differently in IE and than other major browsers. How do i go about marking this correct now from a comment?

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap 4 is flexbox-based by default. And those parts that don't have flexbox enabled by default can be easily enabled: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

That means: You can do everything you are attempting to do with your custom css, you can do all that with native Bootstrap 4 classes alone.

Using native Bootstrap 4 classes is recommended because when you do that you don't need to worry about IE 11 compatibility (because that has already been done and tested which is one of the main points of using Bootstrap in the first place). Whereas unnecessary css hacks will require even more css hacks to fix the problems caused by the original css hacks.